# Disablling event ike click in fa-fa-icon or on any text in typescript

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I am doing one liking button in angular. So, I am using fa fa-thumbs-up to show white background, color background in ngclass. So, on hitting. It will call a typescript function and will change ngclass and updpate server side with API.

Now, what I want is onClicking thumbsup. It will toggle(which is happening). And call that API. So, within that time before getting response I want to disable the click function (click)="toggle()".

```
  <div *ngIf="idea.isDisplay === true" style="text-align:right;border-top:1px solid black;border-bottom:1px solid black" [ngClass]="isLiked == true ? 'liked' : 'not-liked'">
    <i class="fa fa-thumbs-up" style="font-size:30px;" aria-hidden="true"  (click)="toggle()"></i>
       &nbsp;{{likedBy.length}}
  </div>  


toggle()
{
    this.isLiked = !this.isLiked;
    ....//calling observable
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out this will solve you problem. Add a property to your class. and on click of toggle set it to `true`

```
isProcessing: boolean

toggle(){
    if(this.isProcessing){ return; }
    this.isProcessing= true;
    // api call goes here 
}
```

Also when the api returns a response success or error set

```
this.isProcessing = false;
```

This way whenever there is already a api call in progress it wont trigger it again.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: yeah, was waiting for min time to crosss

Answer (score 1):

You can define a flag in your component and use that in the method you call to track whether it is being processed or not. Reset the flag once you get a response from the service. Pseudo code below.

```
isProcessing:boolean = false;

HitLike() {
    if(!isProcessing) {
        this.isProcessing = true;            
        this._yourServiceInstance._serviceMethod.subscribe(result => {
            if(res.success) {
                //change class of button
                this.isProcessing = false;
            }
        }, error => {
            //change button class and show a relevant message
            this.isProcessing = false;
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: No offence but seems similar to my answer just 15 mins later. Also you probably forgot to set the flag to true. That should be done just before the api is called.

Comment: @Manish thanks for pointing it out. I felt that the OP would benefit from seeing a more detailed pseudo code which explains the concept of subscribe as well.